# How To Populate Checkbox dynamically using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have **user** and **role** two table data,I've fetch the data using eloquent and send to my view.
Now, I want to populate user role checkbox dynamically. at this time which is I've written as **hard code**

Here,is my code.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>

         @foreach($user->roles as $role)

        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" {{$user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : ''}}></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" {{$user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : ''}}></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" {{$user->hasRole('Author') ? 'checked' : ''}}></td>
         @endforeach
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

My Eloquent Query.

```
    $users=User::with('roles')->get();

    return view('admin',compact('users'));
```

User Model Relationship.

```
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller, you also need to load all the roles:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
$roles = Role::get();
return view('admin', compact('users', 'roles'));
```

And in the view, do something like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>

        @foreach($roles as $role)
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="role[]" {{ $user->roles->contains($role) ? 'checked' : '' }}></td>
        @endforeach
        <td></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

So, you need to iterate over all roles and not just over roles that user has.